# Restrict traffic to local network and VPN using ufw or iptables

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, iptables, ufw

I want to restrict all traffic from my ubuntu-machine to come or go from the local network (`eth0`) or from or to my VPN (`tun0`).
It should be possible to connect the router in the local network but not possible to leave the local network not using the VPN.

Since i have no experience with iptables and i couldn't  find some how-to i tried ufw but i did not succeed.

Thank you for some hints or code snippets how to come closer!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to operate on the filter table's INPUT chain with a default action of DROP, and then set ACCEPT rules for packets incoming (-i) on each interface.  To improve security, you could also enforce the subnet of the source host, but the rules below will suffice.

```
iptables -t filter -p INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

If you also want to enforce the same thing for traffic leaving the host, also do these:

```
iptables -t filter -p OUTPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Though, if you do this, you really may as well not have the other interfaces.  Also, `lo` is in there because it is the loopback interface; without those rules loopback would no longer work.

Note that if your host is a router, these rules will not apply to traffic it is routing (only to traffic it generates itself or that is destined to it rather than through it).

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I got an error for your first line `iptables -t filter -p INPUT DROP` and it seemed the it should be `iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP`.
**But** after executing this (changed) line, traffic to this machine is interrupted :)
How should i execute this commands to not lose my ssh-connection?

Comment: I updated my question since i was a little unclear. - i think i have to restrict the traffic to the subnet of my machine and to the VPN. @falcon-momot can you help again?